# Redis not working on CentOS

Tags: node.js, redis, centos, nodebb

I'm having trouble installing Redis, this whole week I looked for a solution. I'm needing to install NodeBB running on a CentOS 6 server (with WHM/Cpanel).

Follow the steps http://nodebb-francais.readthedocs.org/projects/nodebb/en/latest/installing/os/centos.html

When I run a test (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-redis-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04) with the command `redis-benchmark -q -n 1000 -c 10 -P 5`, the system returned the error `Writing to socket: Connection refused`.

In attempts I installed multiple times Redis, don't know if this may have affected the functioning now. Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem? Apparently Redis does not run in fact, and it is difficult to find specific content on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the redis package. Your guide is for Ubuntu where it is available in the base repository, it isn't in CentOs. You have to install it via the epel repository.

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm; yum -y --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install redis
chkconfig --add redis
service redis restart
```

You can also install it from source:

```
wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-2.8.3.tar.gz
tar xzvf redis-2.8.3.tar.gz
cd redis-2.8.3
make
make install
chkconfig --add redis
service redis restart
```